# .Net Maui - Binding to array or list?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am trying to figure out how to bind either a list or array of unknown size (whichever is easier, or is possible) to xaml in xaml code only. The list (or array if it works) resides inside a class of `LTEInfo`. Its size is unknown, so I can't provide a label for each element.

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
             x:Class="CellularSignal1.SignalInfo"
             x:DataType="local:SignalInfo"
             Title="Signal">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding lteInfos}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:LTEInfo">
                <Grid Margin="0,10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Pci,StringFormat='PCI: {0:F0}'}"/>
                    <ListView Margin="20">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Bands}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

LTEInfo:

```
namespace CellularSignal1
{
    public class LTEInfo : ConnectionCellInfo, IEquatable<LTEInfo>
    {
        public LTEInfo() : base()
        {
        }

        public int Rssi { get; set; }
        public int Rsrp { get; set; }
        public int Rsrq { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public List<int> Bands { get; set; }
       
   }
}
```

Main:

```
namespace CellularSignal1
{
  public ObservableCollection<LTEInfo> lteInfos { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<LTEInfo>();
  public class implementation1
  {
    LTEInfo lte = new() 
    {
          Pci = pci,
          Level = strength.Level,
          Rssi = strength.Rssi,
          Rsrp = strength.Rsrp,
          Rsrq = strength.Rsrq,
          Bands = new List<int>() {3, 4, 5}
     };
     lteInfos.add(lte);
  }
}
```

My current output shows nothing, even though I know that Bands has integers inside of it.

Comment: Take a look at `ObservableCollection<T>`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn his outer bound source is Observable. The inner lists are not dynamically changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Bands}" />
```

And its nonsense. The List should be bound to the nested ListView ItemSource, and then bind the Label to "." (If you find it required - use converter).

(Btw a hint when writing, if you do not set "DataType", release will show blank ListView, while debug will work fine, so keep in mind this, if its not school project)

Also I suggest CollectionView instead of ListView.
You should check the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you used the `public List<int> Bands { get; set; }` then you bound it to the `<Label Text="{Binding Bands}" />`.

You can change the `Label` to `CollectionView` or `ListView`. Making sure you are using the right data type.